# Getting variable undefined inside try...catch statement

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using Vuex, and this is the code inside my `store.js` file.
I've tested the code in the browser e in the node, and it works.

Why I'm getting `undefined` inside the `try...catch` statement?

```js
// the user object is 
{ name: 'Foo', email: 'foo@bar.com' }
```

```js
actions: {
    login: async ({commit}, user) => {
      console.log('user: ', user) // [OK] print { name: 'Foo', email: 'foo@bar.com' }
      try {
        console.log('user: ', user) // [FAIL] print undefined
      } catch(err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    },
}
```

Comment: I don't see any way this could be happening. `try` is in the same scope, there's nothing that changes the value of the variable after the first `console.log()`.

Comment: Please post your full, actual code. The one without syntax errors.

Comment: This can't be the real code, since you're missing a quote in the first `console.log`.

Comment: Thanks guys for point me in the right way. I found the error in the code after the axios response. Fixed and now it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in one of my similar actions called.... login (sic). I get the correct value from both calls outside and inside of the try block. So my interrogation now is: how do you build your app? Using a bundler, with or without babel or another?

I tend to prefer clean setup for developping, and so not using babel, and bundling with rollup in esm format. Maybe transpiled code is the issue (I know for example that generators created for async methods result in drastically different code).

Comment: I found the error in the code after the axios response. Anyway thanks for the help.